# Как получить число из квантиля?

Tags: python, pandas

У меня есть ряд чисел, откуда я хочу получить квантиль, чтобы использовать его, как условие.

Что-то вроде:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'Bob', '15'],
                   [2,'John', '70'],
                   [3,'Bill', '15'],
                   [4,'Martin', '30'],
                   [5,'Clint', '40'],
                   [6,'Jeff', '100'],
                   [7,'Scott', '90']],  columns=['id','name', 'score']) 

q = df['score'].quantile(q=[0.33]) 
if 50 < q:
     print('ура') else:
     print('не ура')
```

Однако, получаю следующее:

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(),
> a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Я понимаю, что результат функции квантиля я должен преобразовать в число, но как это сделать, я не могу понять.

Comment: Во-первых, у вас тип данных колонки score - object. во-вторых, почитайте документацию про квантиль. если вам нужна одна квантиль с заданным значением на оси по умолчанию, то не нужно ее задавать в виде списка. Короче: `q = df['score'].astype("int").quantile(0.33)`

Comment: вам нужен `q.item()`.

Answer (score 2):

Как уже написал уважаемый [@strawdog](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1347321/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8f/1347345#comment2387559_1347321) в комментарии, вы пытаетесь считать квантили для столбца со строковым типом данных и к тому же, если задать значения `q` в виде списка, то в результате вы получите Pandas.Series с заданными в списке значениями `q` в индексе Series. Поэтому в вашем случае используйте скалярное значение для `q`.

Пример:

```
In [54]: if pd.to_numeric(df["score"], errors="coerce").quantile(q=0.33) > 50:
    ...:     print("ура!")
    ...: else:
    ...:     print(":(")
    ...:
:(
```

Если же вы уверены, что в столбце `score` **все** значения могут быть преобразованы в целое значение, тогда можно использовать более короткий вариант из комментария @strawdog:

```
q = df['score'].astype("int").quantile(0.33)
```